# JavaScript AmCharts

Tags: javascript, css, amcharts

Hi I have a problem with AmCharts.

Chartcursor is offset if body style has `-webkit-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5)` and `-webkit-transform-origin:0px 0px`

```
.bodystyle {
  background: #EEEEF3;
  width: 2048px;
  height: 1536px;
  margin: 0px;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  position: fixed;
}

<body class="bodystyle">
    <div id="chartdiv" class="chart"></div>
</body>
```

ChartCursor:

```
var chartCur = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
chartCur.cursorColor = "#000000";
chartCur.fullWidth = true;
chartCur.valueBalloonsEnabled = true;
```

Comment: Have you tried setting position CSS property to chartdiv? `.chart { position: relative; }`

Comment: This isn't your problem, but ````-webkit```` prefix shouldn't be used for ````transform```` and ````transform-origin```` unless you only want it to affect chrome and safari. Good habit to get into ditching prefixes unless necessary. It is necessary for ````-webkit-tap-highlight-color```` and ````-webkit-overflow-scrolling```` though

Answer (score 0):

Your `transform-origin` is not going to kick in if `position:fixed` is applied.

It also may not be desirable to set a width and height if `chartCur.fullWidth = true;` is enabled. I suggest removing the `width` and `height` properties of your CSS, or changing `.bodystyle` width to 100%.

Also, it's `valueLineBalloonEnabled` not `valueLineBalloonsEnabled` if it matters. Also note that using `scale()` messes up the mouse events. There might be a better way to resize it. Something like disabling the legend and using `max-width:400px;max-height:300px`

> **[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaggedsoftware/ho5ybb46/)**

Comment: I would like to help you fix your problem, can you post a screenshot or an example page so we can check it out?